# Is it possible to develop plugins for Microsoft Office Communicator?

Tags: ms-office, chat, office-communicator

Is it possible to develop plugins for Microsoft Office Communicator?  If so, where does one start -- is there an SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start would be the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ed1cce45-cc22-46e1-bd50-660fe6d2c98c&displaylang=en). I'm not sure if you can create plugins for it, but since it has a API, you can definitely hook into it from external apps or webpages.

Answer (score 3):

The [Custom Tabs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=621C675C-46B7-4F68-ADDC-9F44E5594BFB&displaylang=en) sample app may be just what you are looking for.